# How to open two independent instances of Foxit Reader?

Tags: windows-7, windows, pdf, adobe-reader, foxit-reader

I'm trying to open two PDF files simultaneously, in order to compare their contents, one on the right (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>) and another on the left (<kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>) side of my screen.

Unfortunately I'm trying without success. I already tried to open another Foxit reader, using "open as", but nothing worked.

May I have to install Adobe and Foxit to do that?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There's an option in Foxit Reader's settings that allows multiple instances of the program to be opened.

Go to Tools->Preferences->Documents->Allow Multiple Instances

However in Foxit Reader version 7.2.2: go to Edit->Preferences->Documents->Allow Multiple Instances.

This will open single file in multiple windows not in multiple tabs. Then arrange windows vertically or horizontally to view two files simultaneously.
However, I have not found the split window command like Adobe Reader in Foxit.

Comment: To add to this for Business Version of Foxit which is PhantomPDF You just go to Files>Preferences>Documents> and click the top check box for Multiple instances. A google search for this brought me here but had to tweak it for my version. Added the other way here to help others.

Comment: *Note: The option “Open in multiple instances” has been updated to “Always open files in a new window" since version 13.0 and Version 2023.2.* https://kb.foxit.com/hc/en-us/articles/4978462375060-How-to-enable-disable-multiple-Foxit-PDF-Editor-windows

Answer (score 5):

In Foxit Reader 6.0 this option is here:

File->Preferences->Documents->Allow Multiple Instances

Answer (score 3):

In the others versions the useful funcations can be found here:

Edit->Preferences->Documents->Allow Multiple Instances