# Foxit PDF read - Tile tabs?

Tags: foxit-reader

Is it possible to tile pdf's with Foxit PDF reader? I want to view two tabs side by side to make comparisons.

I see here that I can open multiple instances of the PDF reader but i'd much rather have one instance and tile the tabs just like I do with Excel

[How to open two independent instances of Foxit Reader?](https://superuser.com/questions/358469/how-to-open-two-independent-instances-of-foxit-reader)

David