# How to view two PDF files side-by-side in Foxit?

Tags: windows-vista, pdf

I have Foxit Reader **6.0.3.0524** on a Windows Vista Premium.

I have read [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/358469/how-to-open-two-independent-instances-of-foxit-reader) (How to open two independent instances of Foxit Reader).  I have set Foxit to 'allow multiple instances'.  (**Edit -> Preferences -> Documents -> Allow multiple instances**)  However, I am not able to see the two files side-by-side.  They open in two tabs (one in each tab).  In addition to the 'allow multiple instances' setting, what do I need to do to view the two files side by side so that I don't have to keep clicking on the tabs.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open two independent instances of Foxit Reader?](http://superuser.com/questions/358469/how-to-open-two-independent-instances-of-foxit-reader)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you activate the "Allow multiple instances"-option, you should be able to open an other instance of the Foxit-programm. So you can open the other file in that instance. **That's the only way to see two files side by side.**

1. Click Edit -> Preferences -> Documents -> Allow multiple instances
2. Open the first PDF in Foxit
3. Open the second PDF in another instance of Foxit

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.  I appreciate it. It is silly of me to expect the two files side-by-side in the same window. Althought it clearly says 'multiple INSTANCES', it did not sink in that it means I have to fire up another Foxit instance.  I kept (re)opening the file from the same Foxit instance.    I am unable to give upmark your answer because I get a message that I need a minimum 15 reputation.  Sorry about this.

Comment: You are welcome. :) You can accept my answer by clicking on the tick(√) under the arrows.